# Leaving tiny gap between == in Verbatim (fancyvrb) environment

Tags: fancyvrb

`\texttt{==}` typesets the two equals signs with a tiny gap in between. However,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{JetBrainsMono-Regular.otf}


\begin{document}

\texttt{==}

    \begin{Verbatim}
        ==
    \end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

typesets the two equals signs without the gap.

Is it possible to preserve the gap between `==` in the Verbatim (fancyvrb) environment? If so, how?

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dhX2.png) with texlive 2022 pdflatex

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I gather then, that this has to do with typefaces chosen. I will investigate.

Comment: Thanks for updating the example but your description (and answer post) are a bit misleading as Verbatim and texttt use the same font, and both show the same problem with Jet Brains (from  https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsMono) (You could raise an issue with the font that = ought to not fill its full width)

Comment: This is by design == forms a ligature to a long equals, => forms a ligature to an arrow, etc you can use the NL version from the same source without ligaturesor https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsMono/blob/master/fonts/ttf/JetBrainsMonoNL-Regular.ttf disable the font feature when loading the font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the JetBrains font has a lot of ligatures including `==` ligature to a long =, you can disable this at font loading

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Contextuals = AlternateOff]{JetBrainsMono-Regular.otf}


\begin{document}

\texttt{==}

    \begin{Verbatim}
        ==
    \end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\texttt{}` and Verbatim were using two different (but very similar) fonts. Verbatim font was inherited from Beamer theme, not specified in my preamble, but included in MWE (above).

Added

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\verbatimfont{Inconsolata-Regular.ttf}[NFSSFamily=myverbatimfont]
```

to preamble and specified font within document using

```
\begin{Verbatim}[fontfamily=myverbatimfont]
==
\end{Verbatim}
```

Resolved. (I could also modify the Beamer theme I've been using.)

Comment: As you can see, no one other than yourself could have answered your question as the issue  is just related to code not shown. Please, even now, edit your question so that it has a complete small document that shows a problem so that this post makes sense to future readers.

Comment: I tracked the font specification down to the Beamer template being used. I'll try to extract that and construct and MWE.